# Testing with Web Driver and Selenium through Codeception

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, acceptance-testing, codeception

I know I'll get crap for this but it's worth it if  someone can help.

I can't find a guide, tutorial, or instructions anywhere for installing web driver on a windows machine. I've got a site running on a homestead vagrant box and need a way of running acceptance tests locally. I had tests setup using PhpBrowser but those don't simulate JavaScript. If anyone knows of a guide to do this or a better way to run acceptance tests it would help immensely. I've got Ajax calls so PhpBrowser and resources like it won't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and Run the `selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar` as stated in the comment. I had to add `firefox_binary: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe` under `capabilities:` in my acceptance.suite.yml file. I also added it to the path variable but I'm not sure if that made a difference. Had to add the firefox_binary to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the selenium webserver [the jar file](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar) and run it in a command shell with `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar`. The selenium server will now listen on the default port 4444. If you run your test it should work as expected. Keep in mind that selenium webserver opens firefox and uses it for testing. It's pretty useful for watching the test cases.

If you want a headless test (no visible browser) you need to download [phantomjs](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-windows.zip). Unpack it and run the phantomjs.exe with `--webdriver=4444` as an argument (so `phantomjs.exe --webdriver=4444`).

Comment: I have the jar file downloaded. I have "WebDriver" enabled as my driver. I run the jar and still get a "Cannot find WebDriver" error